# push array into multidimensional array?

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have json_encoded array that i would like to add to using php

```
[{"id":"a","value":"2"},{"id":"b","value":"2"}]
```

I want to add the following to the array above:

```
array("id" => c, "value" => "3")
```

I tried `json_decode` then trying to push the array into that but im confused on how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in array mode rather than object mode:

```
// Default: JSON is decoded as object
$json_object = json_decode($json_string);

// Pass true in the second argument to get an array instead
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, true);

// Push a new entry onto the end
$json_array[] = array("id" => c, "value" => "3");

// Re-encode JSON string, if needed
$json_final_string = json_encode($json_array);
```